# JTextArea does not scroll automatically to most bottom line

Tags: java, swing, awt, jscrollpane, jtextarea

So basically I have a `JScrollPane` which contains a `JTextArea`.

```
public class Console extends JScrollPane {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public Console() {
        super();

        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        setViewportView(textArea);
        setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 400));
}
```

With the setting of the update policy, it automatically scrolls down to the newly added line. However, if I mark text in the text area or scroll up and down myself, this does not work anymore. New lines aren't shown anymore, I have to scroll down myself.

I even tried setting the policy again with each newly added line.

```
public void print(String txt) {
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
    textArea.append(getNewLogMsg(txt));
}
```

Still the automated scrolling does not work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, seems not right, but it works

```
public void print(String txt) {
    textArea.append(getNewLogMsg(txt));
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```